# 'Illegal choice' error while submitting/validating selectbox shown with AJAX

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm making a module where the content type and fields are created by install. Now i want to make one of those fields only to show up when an option is selected. I did this with AJAX, in some way I can't make it work with the field as defined in the module.install file. I have a radio button selector for two options. When selecting the first option there should show up a selectbox with a list of nodes to select. When selecting the second option two textfields should be shown instead. When I try to add content of this type I get the error message (when changing the value from the radio buttons):

An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.

Can someone give me some advice to make this work? Thanks in advance!

---

Here is my code from the install file:

```
function _concert_installed_fields() {
$t = get_t();
return array(
  // other fields left out
'venue_node' => array(
 'field_name' => 'venue_node',
 'label' => 'Select a venue from the list',
 'type' => 'list_integer',
 'cardinality' => '1',
 'foreign keys' => array(),
 'indexes' => array(
   'value' => array(
    0 => 'value',
   ),
  ),
 'module' => 'list',
 'settings' => array(
  'allowed_values_function' => '_concert_content_type_venue_options_list',
  ),
),
'venue_radio' => array(
 'field_name' => 'venue_radio',
 'cardinality' => 1,
 'type' => 'list_boolean',
)
);
```

From my .module file:

```
 function concert_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == "concert_node_form") {
 $form['venue_radio'] = array(
  '#title' => t("Choose a venue from the database or add one manually"),
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(0 => t('Add a venue from the database.'),
                      1 => t('Add a venue manually.'),),
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'concert_venue_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'venue_select',
    'effect' => 'fade',
  ),
);

$form['venue_select'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id = "venue_select">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
);
if (!empty($form_state['values']['venue_radio']) && $form_state['values']['venue_radio']   == "1") {
  $form['venue_node']['#type'] = 'hidden';

  $form['venue_select']['location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('location'),

  );
  $form['venue_select']['venue_city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title'=> t('city'),
  );
}

else {
$form['venue_select']['venue_node'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => _concert_content_type_venue_options_list(),
    '#title' => t('venue node select'),
    '#default_value' => '466', // node id is select value
  );
if (!empty($form_state['values']['venue_node']))
$form['concert_venue_node']['und']['#default_value'] = $form_state['values']['venue_node']; 
}

function concert_venue_callback($form, $form_state) {
   return $form['venue_select'];
}
```

The options from the selectbox are populated by a function in a file accessable for both the .install and the .module file:

```
function _concert_content_type_venue_options_list() {

$results = db_select('node', 'n')
 ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
 ->condition('n.status', 1)
 ->condition('n.type', 'venue')
 ->execute();

$options = array();
  foreach ($results as $node) {
    $options[$node->nid] = $node->title;
  }
return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting #default_value for the 'venue_radio' form element solved my problem: http://drupal.org/node/1545316#comment-5914060
I also changed my code to how it is described in the Ajax altering node form example. Everything is working now in the way I wanted it to. Issue solved.